# New version of Lazyload?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

Does anyone know of another plugin than Lazyload from Applesiini?
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

They have stopped working on it, so it doesn't work in new browsers.  I'm looking for an alternative.

What I need it to do is simply not load images until the user has scrolled to it (but the code is already loaded, so no Ajax load new content).  If you think it is easy to program I more than welcome any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this jQuery code to initiate an Ajax call when a page has scrolled past a particular element:

```
$("body").bind("scroll touchstart touchend",function(){
    if($("body").scrollTop()>=$("#something").offset().top){
        alert("Put an Ajax call here...");
    }
});
```

Simply replace `#something` with the jQuery selector of an element above the element you want to lazy load.

Ad@m

Comment: @adam :  Thanks for that.  But I don't want to load new images on the page.  They are already there but I don't want want to be loaded until the user scrolls over them.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: On the `.bind("scroll")` part, you should read ["Learning from Twitter"](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) by John Resig.

Comment: @jensgram, I dislike John Resigs solution with using an interval. Should be better to set a timeout inside the scroll event and check if that timeout is running or not. Implemented this kind of solution in my answer and it's working fine and only when the user is actually scrolling, without the background polling an interval will introduce.

Comment: @jensgram, just to add to my last comment. I felt that the current throttling solutions were inadequate (slow or otherwise lacking) so decided to throw together my own [jQuery Throttle](https://github.com/mekwall/jquery-throttle) plugin to throttle/debounce functions.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to give it a shot. Borrowed the in-viewport detection from the lazyload project and eventually got it working properly by using the `rel` attribute to specify the url to the images.

Had to use `visiblity: hidden` instead of `display: none` to be able to detect the position of the element, and then do `hide`, remove the `visibility` styling and animate with `fadeIn`.

You can animate it however you like by passing a function to the `animate` option.

Check out this [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/MjuNX/)

Comment: This is gold – you should turn this into a plugin and get mad props.

Comment: @PT, thanks but it's already a plugin. You mean put it up on github or something? I might just do that :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the plugin page again. It has been updated recently. Especially the [demo page which uses scrollstop event](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_gazillion.html). This event is not provided by default. Code is taken from James Padolseys excellent [special scroll events for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/) article.